# dynamic naming for saving files

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string-formatting, naming

I'm not sure if the correct term is dynamic naming, but I want the name of my the files I'm creating, to change with the stock tickers I have in my list.

```
stocks_query = ['AAPL','OPK'] #current stocks I have in my list/tuple
stocks.to_pickle('\\Users\Moondra\MachineLearning\stockPredictor-master\{}.pkl'.format(stocks_query))   #stocks is a dataframe
```

yields something like this:

`['AAPL', 'OPK'].pkl`

But I want it to be cleaner, and am looking for 
`aapl_opk.pkl`    or `AAPL_OPK.pkl`

I played around with regular expressions but I really didn't know to complete this task.

```
     re.findall(r'(\w+)', str(stocks_query))
stocks.to_pickle('\\Users\Moondra\MachineLearning\stockPredictor-master\{}.pkl'.format(re.findall(r'(\w+)', str(stocks_query))))
```

This yields the same result as above; I have no idea how to put the '_' in between the stock names, when I'm naming my file.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Playing around some more, with the tuple

```
 stocks_query = ('AAPL', 'OPK', 'GOOGL')
str(stocks_query)
>>  "('AAPL', 'OPK', 'GOOGL')" , I was able to get this far using `re.sub`

x =re.compile(r'[)(]')
y = re.compile(r"[']")

re.sub(y, '_', re.sub(x, "", str(stocks_query))).replace(',', '')
```

which resulted in   `AAPL_ _OPK_ _GOOGL_`

Ideal output is `AAPL_OPK_GOOGL`

Re seems to be a very powerful tool, and I have feeling it's possible to do what I'm attempting to do, but I can't find the right anchors/modifers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
stocks_query = ['AAPL', 'OPK', 'GOOGL']
filename = '_'.join(stock_query)
stocks.to_pickle('\\Users\Moondra\MachineLearning\stockPredictor-master\{}.pkl'.format(filename))
```

Comment: Wow, this seems to work perfectly and so simple.  I'm will play around with a bit and make sure there are no problems.